# Python: Keep trailing zeroes while concatenating two hex strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file which contains data in two columns. The data is in decimal format.

I am trying to convert the data into hexadecimal format, then concatenate it.

I am able to convert and concatenate when data in column2 is non-zero.

For example: *Column1 = 52281* and *Column2 = 49152*, then i am able to get *CC39C000*. (hex(52281) = CC39 and hex(49152) = C000).

However, if data in Column2 is zero:-

*Column1 = 52281* and *Column2 = 0*, then i get *CC390* instead of *CC390000*.

Following is my code snippet:-

```
file=open( inputFile, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
        col1,col2=int(line[0]),int(line[1])
        newstr = '{:x}'.format(col1)+'{:x}'.format(col2)
```

When the data in column2 is 0, i am expecting to get 0000.

How can i modify my code to achieve this??

Comment: You need the zero pad format option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
a=52281
b=0
```

You can convert yo hex and calculate the longest string to fill with zeros

```
hex_a = hex(a)[2:] # [2:] removes the trailing 0x you might want to use [3:] if you have negative numbers
hex_b = hex(b)[2:]
longest=max(len(hex_a), len(hex_b))
```

Then you can fill with 0 with the `zfill` method:

```
print(hex_a.zfill(longest) + hex_b.zfill(longest))
```

If you only need 4 characters you can do `zfill(4)`

If I am trying to adapt your code, which is hard to test because I do not have access to the file,

```
 file=open( inputFile, 'r')
 reader = csv.reader(file)
 for line in reader:
    col1,col2=int(line[0]),int(line[1])
    hex_col1 = hex(col1)[2:] if col1>=0 else hex(col1)[3:]
    hex_col2 = hex(col2)[2:] if col2>=0 else hex(col2)[3:]
    longest = max(len(hex_col1), len(hex_col2))
    newstr = hex_col1.zfill(longest) + hex_col2.zfill(longest)
```

Comment: When i do *line[1].zfill(4), '0'* changes to '0000'. However, ***col1,col2=int(line[0]),int(line[1])*** again changes '0000' to '0'. So, finally, i still get CC390 instead of CC390000.

Comment: You want to zfill AFTER converted to hex, not while reading, it will indeed remove the trailling zeros if you convert to int

Comment: @Sandrocottus Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, still trying to  modify my code to do that. Does not work!

Comment: @Sandrocottus I gave it a shot, tell me if you got any errors

Comment: Gotcha!! Thanks a ton :-)